# How to check is extension installed in Safari?

Tags: javascript, safari

There is the way to check: is my extension is installed in Safari or not?
And if yes call it extension..

Answer (score 0):

tips:
   1.send a request to server like "qq" to wait response. after 10s more or 
     less ,you can guess if be installed

thx.

Comment: Its not clear what you recommend...please expand reply.